# log of infinite product converse

Tags: summation, logarithms

I have seen that there is this property

$\log \Pi_{n=1}^\infty a_n= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(a_n) $.

Hence, I am wondering if there exists any such property for the converse, i.e.

$\log \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k =?$

Comment: Not really in general.  Similarly not for $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \log(a_n)$